# how to handle the key pressed inside another key click event in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

i have a textblock and few buttons 
what i wanna do is see if the last char in textblock is ^ 
if so i want the next all numbers to go in superscript

here is what i did

```
  private void buttonxn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + "x^";

  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      int len=textBlock1.Text.Length;
      string x = textBlock1.Text.Substring(len-1, 1);
      if(x=="^")
      {
          textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + "\x2070";
      }

      else
          textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + "1";
  }
```

but this only helps if the power is one digit how to make it applicable for like x^12 or something else
for that i was trying to make a string and check

```
     string power ={ "\x2070", "\x00b9", "\x00b2", "\x00b3", "\x2074", "\x2075", "\x2076", "\x2077", "\x2078", "\x2079" };
```

now in the click event of all the button i can check while the last char is in 'power' so the next digit button pressed will also be in power until anyother key like +,- is pressed....
i hope i made myself clear....sorry if i dint am rather new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to seperate your current application state from your UI. This code would be a simplified example, but it would be good to look into patterns that do this (MVC,MVP,MVVM). While using these patterns is mostly overkill for very small applications, what can be learned from them is pretty neat.
Basically you want to switch states on certain buttons, if they affect the behaviour of other buttons. In this example your +/-... buttons would switch back to default.

```
        public enum EntryState
        {
            Default,
            Power
        }

        private EntryState _state = EntryState.Default;

        private void buttonxn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + "x^";
            _state = EntryState.Power;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_state == EntryState.Power)
                textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + "\x2070";
            else
                textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + "1";
        }
```